# Mixed precision training leads to NaN-loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've been following the [Mixed Precision Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision). Hence, I am setting:

```py
keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy(mixed_precision)
```

and wrap the optimizer like so:

```py
if mixed_precision.startswith('mixed'):
    logger.info(f'Using LossScaleOptimizer for mixed-precision policy "{mixed_precision}"')
    optimizer = keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer)
```

My model has simple `Dense` layer as an output which I set to 'float32`

```py
# Set dtype explicitly in last layer for mixed-precision training (float32 for numeric stability).
self.output_dense = layers.Dense(vocab_size, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and a custom `train_step()` implementation which I modified to this:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    model_loss = self.loss_fn(
        inputs,
        y_true=y_true,
        mask=mask
    )

    is_mixed_precision = isinstance(self.optimizer, mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer)

    # We always want to return the unmodified model_loss for Tensorboard
    if is_mixed_precision:
        loss = self.optimizer.get_scaled_loss(model_loss)
    else:
        loss = model_loss

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)

    if is_mixed_precision:
        gradients = self.optimizer.get_unscaled_gradients(gradients)

    return model_loss, gradients
```

However, after a while my loss is still becoming `NaN`:

[image]

Outside I am confirming whether or not the policy has been recognized by the model:

```py
logger.info(f'Mixed-precision policy: {mixed_precision}')
logger.info(f'Compute dtype:          {model.compute_dtype}')
logger.info(f'Variable dtype:         {model.variable_dtype}')
```

```
keras.py:216] Mixed-precision policy: mixed_float16
keras.py:217] Compute dtype:          float16
keras.py:218] Variable dtype:         float32
```

But I can tell that this is the case due to the `NaN` loss..

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong or missing out? Any idea how I could track down the issue here?

Comment: Is it possible to give some reproducible code, maybe with `mnist`?

Comment: @M.Innat Hi! Thanks for responding. Fortunately I think I've already found the issue (see my answer). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rethinking I think I was able to find the issue. It was located in my custom multi-head attention layer. More specifically, the issue seemed to be the masking where I used `value.dtype.min` in order to apply a mask to the logits like to:

```py
logits += value.dtype.min * (1.0 - mask)
```

It's interesting that this even worked in the first place. Thinking about it, there should be a high chance that you'll get an underflow from the beginning yet I was able to train the model for some time until `NaN` occurred.

Anyway, my solution was to give it some room so I simply divide the minimum value of the `dtype` by two:

```py
logits += (value.dtype.min / 2.0) * (1.0 - mask)
```